# Unable to pass parameters using l() since the parameter is in drupal_render

Tags: php, drupal-6, hyperlink

This is my code:

```
 function theme_freeway_dashboard_details($form) {

$pidobtained = $_GET['project_id'] ;

    $rows = array();
    foreach (element_children($form) as $key) {

            $row = array();                 
                $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['FileID']));
                $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['Filename']));
                $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['SourceLanguageID']));
                $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['TargetLanguageID']));
                $row[] = array('data' => l(drupal_render($form[$key]['StatusID']),'user/1/freewayRetrieve',array('query' => array('fileId'=> $row[0],'projectID'=> $pidobtained))));                            
                $row[] = array('data' => drupal_render($form[$key]['StatusDescription']));                      
                $rows[] = $row;


            }
            $header = array();
            $header[] = t('File ID');
            $header[] = t('File Name');
            $header[] = t('Source Language');
            $header[] = t('Target Language');
            $header[] = t('Status ID');
            $header[] = t('Status Description');


            //$output = theme('table', $header, $rows,array('size'=>10, 'class' => 'table_class'));
            $output = theme('table', $header, $rows);
            $output .= drupal_render($form);


        return $output;

    }
```

I am trying to pass paremeter on click on the link, the parameter being FileID. The URL being generated as a result of the above code is

```
   'http://localhost/drupalTheme/user/1/freewayRetrieve?fileId[data]=157960&projectID=437286' .
```

Now when i try to get the values from this URL from the subsequesnt function using

```
   <?php
    $fileIdbtained = $_GET['fileId[data]'] ;
    $pidobtained = $_GET['projectID'] ;
    ?>
```

I am getting the value for projectID but not for fileID. Is this the correct way to go about accessing the parameters?
Would like to have your views.

Thanks 
A

Comment: What does `var_dump($form[$key]['FileID']);` print? You need to know how the `$form[$key]['FileID']` variable is structured if you want to get the plain FileID string out of it.

Comment: I have updated the code .Using row[0] did give me the value but with the '[data]' . The var_dump shows this value (http://pastebin.com/8iRRLftu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear: In your foreach loop, `$form[$key]['FileID']` is a [FAPI element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#elements).

In other words: In every iteration of the loop, the variable `$form[$key]['FileID']` (as well as `$form[$key]['Filename']` and the others) is a PHP [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) which has a specific structure.

This "specific structure" is one that is expected by [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/6) so that it knows how to "render" the element (that is, generate a string of HTML).

Now, for the case where you want to get the actual semantic value (i.e. 157960) of `$form[$key]['FileID']` without the HTML, **first** you obviously have to stop passing it through [drupal_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/6).

Then, since `$form[$key]['FileID']` is an array (which happens to hold the structure of a FAPI element, as I mentioned previously) you need to access whichever of *its* elements holds the actual data you're after. And according to your latest update, that element would be the one with a key of **'#value'**.

So, what you want to use is `$form[$key]['FileID']['#value']`. That is, the line of code that prepares that row, should be:

```
$row[] = array('data' => l(drupal_render($form[$key]['StatusID']),'user/1/freewayRetrieve',array('query' => array('fileId'=> $form[$key]['FileID']['#value'],'projectID'=> $pidobtained))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could install the module "devel". It shows you the available array's and values within them on the page you're at. Using this module, you can click through the array's just like clicking through the CSS/HTML structure with Firebug. You could at least check to see if the value you're looking for is somewhere in an existing array.

Also when loading the page try output the array using

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($content);
```

See if the value is somewhere within that array

Comment: I am seeing the output in my UI. This is the table i am seeing as a result of the above code http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1180-217.html. On click of the link 'Ready' seen in the first row i need to pass the File ID 157960 as the paramter so the next page URL must be 'http://localhost/drupalTheme/user/1/freewayRetrieve?fileId=157960' . The difficulty i am facing is to eke out that value of fileID from inside of the line $row i have mentioned in my earlier paste.